# How to require modules with RequireJS

Tags: html, requirejs

I am working with [RequireJS](https://requirejs.org/) and I am having some troubles while require local libraries.

I have created a JS file to require the library which I have installed with `npm`

**JS**

```
function synthesizeToAudioFile() {
            require(["node_modules/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/distrib/browser/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.sdk.bundle.js"], function (sdk) {
            var synthesizer = new sdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

    }
}
```

Why is `sdk` still `undefined`? I get the following error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'AudioConfig' of undefined

The library is correctly loaded but the variable is undefined.

Comment: Can you edit your question to write the error message ?

Comment: Sorry, I just copied wrongly the message. I have already updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequireJS is a library for using AMD style modules.

The library you installed from NPM is a CommonJS module designed to run under Node.JS.

AMD and CommonJS have some similarities, but are different formats and are not freely interchangeable.

If you want to use Microsoft's Cognitive Services Speech SDK in a browser, then follow the [instructions for using it in a browser](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/quickstart/javascript/browser) instead of trying to hack the Node.js module into working outside of Node.js.

Comment: Hi Quentin. The example that is in that repository, follows the same structure that I am using, right? According to the example it uses the same library, with a different method. The token is not even used unless you run a server so i do not really understand the difference. Do you mean that I should create an script in my HTML file?